# CCTextureCache holding memory issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I've been trying to find out for the last 2 days why even after I tell cocos2d to remove textureatlas
it keeps holding memory.

I have no leeks on intruments, I'm debbuging inside CCTextureCache class and it removes just time

I've tried all the obvious ways to remove texture atlas from cache ex: [[CCDirector sharedDirector] purgeCachedData]; with no success

I'm very hopeless, any help?

Edit:
I'm having the same problem than this guy [LINK](http://forum.cocos2d-swift.org/t/removing-sprite-sheet-plist-and-textures-pvr-not-freeing-up-memory/13949/11) , my game has 1 texture atlas for each level and I repeat the player sprites each image texture atlas files which works great.

my idea was having about up to 30 levels in the game, where it would cost disk space and Assuming I was able to free the memory from the previous texture atlas belonging to the previous level, it would work just fine.

but because I can't find a way to free the memory, the game consumes lots of memory in the 5th level....  it is very frustrating.

any tips are appreciated, thanks

**Edit**:

I found out what is going on, I have some animations that executed a selector at the end of it. I can't remove those selectors, or if I do, I will have to work a lot. I'm pretty upset because the removeallselectors method just doesnt work

Comment: if a texture is removed from the cache but still remains in memory, something is holding on to it. Naturally this will be a sprite using the texture, but could also be any strong ivar/property. Very common are retain cycles, these do not show up as leaks. Verify that your level and all nodes inside it deallocate properly.

Comment: you're right, my ccspritebatchnode keeps retain count 1, I freed enverything from it but it keeps returning 1...oh boy